# How to align HTML span at center of highchart donut graph with responsive design?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am using Highcharts.js for drawing a do-nut graph.

Here i need legends just right to graph and a 'span' outside the container(svg) on the center of graph. Legends work properly, while 'span' doesn't align at the center of graph on responsive view.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zgLm44q5/)

```
var chartDiv = document.getElementById('container');
var textX = $(chartDiv).width()/2;
var textY = $(chartDiv).height()/2 ;
var span = '<span id="pieChartInfoText" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;">';
span += '<span class="centerText">'+Math.round((response.engagement / response.traffic || 0) * 100) + '%</span><br></span>';

$("#addText").append(span);
span = $('#pieChartInfoText');
span.css('left', textX + (span.width() * -0.5));
span.css('top', textY + (span.height() * -0.5));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by using chart 'load' callback.
Refer [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load)

```
events: {
    load: function() {
        var chart = this,
        rend = chart.renderer,
        pie = chart.series[0],
        left = chart.plotLeft + pie.center[0],
        top =  chart.plotTop + pie.center[1],
        text = rend.text(Math.round((response.engagement / response.traffic || 0) * 100) + '%', left,  top).attr({'text-anchor': 'middle','class': 'middleText'}).add();
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zgLm44q5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things going wrong here but the main thing ist this: the circle is actually not in the center of the screen, so the text is but the circle is not you need to adjust the text position to that of the circle offest. plus body has a margin and is not 100% height

also this part here sets the height and the width so we can then calculate the percentage offset

```
var $addText =  $("#addText");
                $addText.append($span)
                .height($addText.height())
                .width($addText.width());
```

see this solution
http://jsfiddle.net/zgLm44q5/1/

also I optimised you code a bit, but there are still thing that could be written more elegantly